Unable to exclude foreign keys in django
I'm failing to get Profiles whithout an Interaction. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Interaction(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

#test.py
class TestQueries(TestCase):
    def test_get_profiles_without_interaction(self):
        profile_with_interaction = Profile.objects.get(username='foobar')
        interactions_from_profile = Interaction.objects.filter(
            user_id=profile_with_interaction)
        assert interactions_from_profile
        
        #####FAILS#####
        all_profiles_without_interaction = Profile.objects.exclude(
            pk__in=Interaction.objects.all())
        assert profile_with_interaction not in all_profiles_without_interaction


You can exclude by using:
Profile.objects.filter(interaction=None)
You can also limit the options for ModelForms by using limit_choices_to=… [Django-doc]:
class Interaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        limited_choices_to={'interaction': None},
    )
In this specific case, you actually can enforce it with a unique ForeignKey: a OneToOneField model field [Django-doc]:
class Interaction(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        Profile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


Note: Normally one does not add a suffix …_id to a ForeignKey field, since Django
will automatically add a "twin" field with an …_id suffix. Therefore it should
be user, instead of user_id.


Excellent points. I like in particular your note about not adding the suffix
